# Is it possible to tell the type of image just from a remote path?

Tags: php, image, mime-types

I'm working on what is effectively a watermarking system, where the user has a URL something like this.

```
https://api.example.com/overlay?image_path=http://www.theuserssite.com/image.ext&other=parameters
```

I'm wondering if the users image_path is something like `www.theuserssite.com/image?image_id=123`, there's no extension in the url, so I can't tell what type of file the image is.

Is there anyway I can get what the file type is just from a remote path?

Comment: Download the image temporary to your sever, then check the mime-type with `finfo_file` ( and maybe some other checks ). Then remove it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, not without calling and loading the image to check its type. try using `getimagesize` PHP function.

example:

```
//https://api.example.com/overlay?image_path=http://www.theuserssite.com/image.ext
    $var = "http://www.theuserssite.com/image.ext";
    $output = getimagesize($var);

    $output[2] = image MIME type.
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought `getimagesize` only worked on local files. I'll accept this one SO let's me.

Comment: the PHP manual shows examples of getimagesize working on remote files. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 1):

Martin is right.
PHP must download the image before it is able to verify the image type.
You could give it a try by requesting the headers of the http request.
But these can be easily wrong / spoofed by the other side.

Comment: The solution Martin posted will work well in my case, so I'll accept that once SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (if exists on your system) - make the request and parse response:

```
$ch = curl_init('www.theuserssite.com/image?image_id=123');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$results = split("\n", trim($result));

foreach ($results as $row)
{
        if (strtok($row, ':') == 'Content-Type')
        {
            $exploded = explode(":", $row);
            echo trim($exploded[1]);
        }
}
```

As stated [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Background)

> The HTTP server responds with a status line (indicating if things went well), response headers and most often also a response body.

Thus there is no need to store the actual file just interpret the result.